# ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE in ajax call in Method Type GET

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having a HTTPS Azure Odata Web Api. and a HTTPS MVC UI application
When i am trying to access a method in Web API it is throwing a error as

```
"ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE"
EG . 
**WEB API Method** 
GetDetails()
{
return "okay ";
}

UI Ajax call
var Url = "https://XXXXXXX.com/" + 'odata/XXXXX';;

$.ajax({
                url: Url,
                async: false,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                type: "GET",
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result.Token
                },

                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success");


                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                },
                failure: function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
```

i have tried with datatype as JSON too
i have tried adding content type too.

Answer (score 0):

I got it once, and restarting the browser solved it. I think its got to do with your ssl certificate

Comment: i have restarted the browser but still i have those :(